# Rails query with referenced attribute in the where

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

example model Users :

`create_table "users"
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.boolean  "internal"
end`

needs to be queried with "admin" or "internal" in the where clause of the SQL query.  At the time of writing the query, it is not known which boolean will be used, so a variable, say `usertype`, is used to store the string "admin" or "internal".  It basically means I would like to use a referenced attribute in my where clause.

Doing the following query :

`User.select("id").where("#{usertype} = 't'")`

works fine in my development sqlite database (since sqlite stores true as 't' and false as 'f'), but I guess that using the same query on another database (Mysql or Postrgres e.g.) might not work.

Alternatively I tried

`User.select("id").where("#{usertype} = ?", true)`

it also works and does not use the sqlite-specific 't'. However, is this a good and database independent solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `true` or `false` (or variables or code which will evaluate 'truthy' or 'falsy`) and let rails handle the translation into however your DBMS stores booleans.

You do this in your second example

```
User.select("id").where("#{usertype} = ?", true)
```

So, the answer is "yes this is a good, database-independent solution".  But, you can make it a bit neater: if all your conditions are of the "=" variety then you can use a hash, like

```
{:foo => "bar"}
{"foo" => "bar"}
```

which are both equivalent to

```
["foo = ?", "bar"]
```

This means in your case you can dispense with the string evalution and just pass your variable in.

```
User.select("id").where({usertype => true})
```

or, if you want to skip the optional `{` & `}`

```
User.select("id").where(usertype => true)
```

**Edit**: reply to comment about using a dynamically defined method in your ruby code, to get a value from an object.

You can use the `send` method to call the appropriate accessor on the object.  For example,

```
@foo.bar == 123
```

is equivalent to

```
@foo.send("bar") == 123
```

So, in your example you would say

```
a.send(usertype)
```

As a sidenote, if you wanted to **set** the value of usertype (which i don't think would make sense in your case, but just an an illustration), you would need to call the "setter" version of the method, which would be either `admin=` or `internal=`.  So, in this case you **would** need to use string evaluation:

```
@user.send("#{usertype}=", "foo")
```

which is like saying

```
@user.admin = "foo"
```

or

```
@user.internal = "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  I am new to ruby and rails and still at the bottom of the learning curve....now if I would move the check for truth from the where clause to a separate test after finding the record, like `a = User.find("id")` and then a.admin or a.internal, how could I use the "usertype" variable in this case ?